# check if value of column 2 contains in column 1 in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to check if fav column from table2 contains the value of the property column.

here is my query

```
SELECT name, title, property FROM table2, table1 where property like'%'+(select fav from table2 where name = 'pritam')+'%'
```

but this returns 0 rows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you intend to use an explicit join here:

```
SELECT name, title, property
FROM table2 t2
INNER JOIN table1 t1
    ON INSTR(property, fav) > 0
WHERE
    name = 'pritam';
```

Note that you should always try to use table aliases whenever possible.

Comment: Thank you for your reply it worked, but now I want to do the exact opposite query how can I do that?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "exact opposite" by my general feeling is that you should open a new question for this.

Comment: please check this question

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62760932/sql-query-to-check-if-substring-of-column-1-contains-is-value-of-another-column