# Sql query to check if substring of column 1 contains is value of another column

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 2 tables column col1 of table1 has values abc, def, ghi

The value of the column col2 of the second table contains one of the above values.

Now I want the list of all rows of table2 which are the part of the value of col1

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results and an appropriate database tag.

Answer (score 2):

Please use below syntax to get your data,

```
select t2.* from table1 t1
inner join table2 t2
on (t1.col1 = t2.col2);
```

Also please tag appropriate tag as well as provide sample data to make every one understand and get proper solution